# how to remove a delimeter ; and drop duplicate values from the column

Tags: python, pandas

```
CaseNumber  Value   Open            crs               
03820567    1   Yes              2375636
03820573    1   Yes               2367131
03820587    1   Yes               2374597
03820598    1   Yes               2367429
03820599    2   Yes               2367131; 2342755
03820619    1   Yes               2377137
03820627    1   Yes                2367429
03820632    1   Yes               2342755

This is my data here in crs column i have to get count of unique values 

My output should be 
        crs               
        2375636
        2367131
        2374597
        2367429
        2342755
        2377137
          crs.count() = 6
I tried code firstly spliting the delimeter ; into next row with casenumber  then i can get unique number count easily but somehow i stuck in it.

[![
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LehCg.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LehCg.png)  this the code i used  but i got the out as below 
    but i got out put as

```
    CaseNumber  CRs
0   3820567       [2375636]
1   3820573        [2367131]
2   3820587        [2374597]
3   3820598        [2367429]
4   3820599        [2308266; 2342755]
5   3820619         [2377137]
6   3820627         [2321772
```

this the code i used  but i got the out as below 
    but i got out put as

Comment: code i used is  new_df = pd.DataFrame(df1.CRs.str.split(';').tolist(), index=df1.CaseNumber).stack()
new_df = new_df.reset_index([0, 'CaseNumber'])
new_df.columns = ['CaseNumber', 'CRs']
new_df

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is the count of unique elements in `csr` here's one approach. You could start by using [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), and obtaining a list from the result. Then use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flatten the list, turn it into a `set` and take the `len`:

```
from itertools import chain
len(set(chain(*df.crs.str.split('; ').values.tolist())))
# 6
```

Answer (score 1):

If need only count unique values use `set comprehension` with split:

```
out = len(set(y for x in  df.crs.str.split('; ') for y in x))
#alternative
#out = len(set(y for x in  df.crs for y in x.split('; ')))
print (out)
6
```

If need filtered DataFrame in output first extract column by [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html), [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html),[`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original and remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
s = (df.pop('crs')
       .str.split('; ', expand=True)
       .stack()
       .reset_index(1, drop=True)
       .rename('crs'))

df1 = (df.join(s)
         .drop_duplicates('crs')
         .reset_index(drop=True))

print (df1)
   CaseNumber  Value Open      crs
0     3820567      1  Yes  2375636
1     3820573      1  Yes  2367131
2     3820587      1  Yes  2374597
3     3820598      1  Yes  2367429
4     3820599      2  Yes  2342755
5     3820619      1  Yes  2377137
```

Comment: @tiru - Super :) Glad can help!